# redux doesn't update props immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a functional component in a react native application, and I'm dispatching an HTTP call. If some error occurs, I store it in redux, the problem is when I access to the error value, I get null

```
function IncomingOrder(props) {

  function acceptOrder(orderId, coords) { // I call this from a button
    const response = await actions
      .accept(token, orderId, coords) //this is the async function
      .catch((e) => {
        showError(props.error);
    });
  }
  ...
}

...


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    token: state.auth.token,
    error: state.deliveries.error
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      accept: (token, id, coords) => {
        return dispatch(Order.accept(token, id, coords));
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: There is just so much info missing from this question... what's the code, where's the `dispatch()`, is `accept()` an async action creator? where is this called from? why are you passing `props.error` if it's not in the scope, did you mean to pass `e` instead?  why are you calling `catch()` on an `await`ed promise?  Please put some more effort in the question, otherwise we won't be able to help you as there is not much info to work with.

Comment: I see that you're catching an error, which implies that an error is being thrown by your accept function. Are you perchance throwing the error in Order.accept? If so, it would prevent the dispatch from occurring since the error would be thrown before Order.accept returned. If this is the case, the redux store would never be updated. Is there a reason you aren't pulling the error message from the thrown error?

Comment: @AlexBroadwin I removed the catch and I'm still getting null
`const response = await actions
      .accept("token", orderId, coords)
    console.log("TCL: accept -> error", error); //null`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely on `acceptOrder()` async action creator.

Redux `dispatch` wont update immediately after your promise resolves/rejects. So by the time your error handler (`Promise.prototype.catch or catch(){}`) kicks in, there is no guarantee the action has been dispatched or the state tree updated.

What you want to do instead is to have this logic on the async action creator

```
// action module Order.js
export const accept = (token, id, coords) => dispatch => {
  fetch('/my/api/endpoint')
    .then(response => doSomethingWith(response))
    .catch(err => dispatch(loadingFailed(err)); // <----- THIS is the important line

}


// reducer.js
// you want your reducer here to handle the action created by loadingFailed action creator. THEN you want to put the error in the state.


// IncomingOrder.js
function IncomingOrder(props) {
  function acceptOrder(orderId, coords) { // I call this from a button
    actions.accept(token, orderId, coords);
    // You don't need to wait for this, as you're not gonna work with the result of this call. Instead, the result of this call is put on the state by your reducer.
}

  render() {
    const { error } => this.props;  // you take the error from the state, which was put in here by loadingFailed() 

    if (error) {
      // render your error UI
    } else {
      // render your regular UI
    }
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    token: state.auth.token,
    error: state.deliveries.error  // <--- I suppose your error is already here (?)
  };
}
```

Comment: I'm using redux-promise-middleware which creates actions for loading, fulfilled and rejected when a promise is dispatched, so when the promise is rejected, I get an ACCEPT_ORDER_REJECTED action where I set the error

Comment: I removed the catch and I'm still getting null
`const response = await actions
      .accept("token", orderId, coords)
    console.log("TCL: accept -> error", error); //null`

Comment: You won't see the `error` after calling `.accept()`, the error exists asynchronously when redux decides to update the state. If you call console log after calling .accept() you'll get null.  Instead, you should have a case to run logic `if (error !== null)`, and then the component will execute that logic when the props are updated by redux